# Python collage of four image together

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, image-resizing, image-manipulation

I am trying to combine 4 images, image 1 on top left, image 2 on top right, image 3 on bottom left and image 4 on bottom right. However, my images are different sizes and not sure how to resize the images to same size. I am pretty new to Python and this is my first time using PIL.

I have this so far (after opening the images)

```
img1 = img1.resize(img2.size)
img1 = img1.resize(img3.size)
img1 = img1.resize(img4.size)
```

Comment: Do the image have the same aspect ratio? An example of the images would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

This shall suffice your basic requirement.
This shall suffice your basic requirement.

Steps:

- Images are read and stored to list of arrays using io.imread(img) in
  a list comprehension.
- We resize images to custom height and width.You can change IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT as per your need with respect
  to the input image size.
- You just have to pass the location of  n
  images (n=4 for your case) to the function.
- If you are
  passing more than 2 images (for your case 4), it will work create 2
  rows of images.  In the top row, images in the first half of the list
  are stacked and the remaining ones are placed in bottom row using
  hconcat().
- The two rows are stacked vertically using vconcat().
- Finally, we convert the result to RGB image using
  image.convert("RGB") and is saved using image.save().

The code:

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from skimage import io

IMAGE_WIDTH = 1920
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 1080

def create_collage(images):
    images = [io.imread(img) for img in images]
    images = [cv2.resize(image, (IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT)) for image in images]
    if len(images) > 2:
        half = len(images) // 2
        h1 = cv2.hconcat(images[:half])
        h2 = cv2.hconcat(images[half:])
        concat_images = cv2.vconcat([h1, h2])
    else:
        concat_images = cv2.hconcat(images)
    image = Image.fromarray(concat_images)

    # Image path
    image_name = "result.jpg"
    image = image.convert("RGB")
    image.save(f"{image_name}")
    return image_name
images=["image1.png","image2.png","image3.png","image4.png"]
#image1 on top left, image2 on top right, image3 on bottom left,image4 on bottom right
create_collage(images)
```

To create advanced college make you can look into this:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/275727/python-3-script-to-make-photo-collages